# Android loading URL images into recyclerviews

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Creating a recycleview that I need to pull images from a url location.

In the future, I would want to pull the URL's from a database, but I cant get one URL to pull.

Here is the code that loads an image from the local drive

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    CellFeedViewHolder holder = (CellFeedViewHolder) viewHolder;
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        holder.ivFeedCenter.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_feed_center_1);
    } else {
        holder.ivFeedCenter.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_feed_center_2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use library like picasso, fresco for image downloading. BTW i am not seeing your list data anywhere. You need data of an list item here. the data should have your url

Comment: @Shubendra I've added picasso, but I cant figure out where the .load code goes ?

Comment: Search about google samples. There is a project name XYZTouristAttraction. Look at the source code of this project.